# Elegant Papers in analytic number theory such as Thomas Wright

Tags: analytic-number-theory, research, mathematicians, carmichael-numbers

I've been reading various papers relating bounded gaps between Primes, sieve theory, Carmichael numbers and the like and Thomas wright's papers stood out to me as being very well written and yet proving non trivial results. I found his papers to be a good way to also get interested in a topic such as his paper on siegel zeroes and K tuples Conjecture. It like seeing math tools in action before finding out what they are.

Are their any other authors who struck you as such? Maybe their papers taught you a lot or felt very deep in ideas or just very well written?

Comment: For my money anything by GH Hardy is a treat.

Comment: Damn, I got his collected works and forgot about it entirely. Any specific paper?

Comment: Also posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450635/papers-that-struck-you-in-some-aspect-readability-elegance-etc